# Tkinter: Updating progressbar when a function is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

Imagine the following simple example:

```
def doNothing():
  sleep(0.5)
  barVar.set(10)
  sleep(0.5)
  barVar.set(20)
  sleep(0.5)
  barVar.set(30)

mainWindow = Tk()
barVar = DoubleVar()
barVar.set(0)
bar = Progressbar(mainWindow, length=200, style='black.Horizontal.TProgressbar', variable=barVar, mode='determinate')
bar.grid(row=1, column=0)
button= Button(mainWindow, text='Click', command=doNothing)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

**What I get** when I run this, the progressbar is already at 30% when clicking the button, no progress in front of me. Like attached:

[image]

**What I need:**  ***I can see the progress in front of me*** (not hanging then suddenly 30%)

**Update:**
I upadted the code according to @Bernhard answer, but still I ***can not see the progress in front of me***. Just a sudden jump of 30% after waiting 1.5 sec

**Seocnd Update:**
I'm only using sleep here as a simulation for a process that takes time, like connecting over ssh and grabing some info.

Comment: don't ever use `sleep()` with tkinter. sleep just freezes the tkinter instance because tkinter is a single thread program. Instead use the built in tkinter method called `after()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find the solution.

simply add `mainWindow.update()` after each progress. So the final code would be:

```
def doNothing():
  sleep(0.5)
  barVar.set(10)
  mainWindow.update()
  sleep(0.5)
  barVar.set(20)
  mainWindow.update()
  sleep(0.5)
  barVar.set(30)
  mainWindow.update()
```

Comment: The problem with this code is you are not addressing the real problem but using a bad workaround to visualize the updating of the loading bar. The tkinter application is still frozen and not usable during these sleep calls. At no point should your have code in your program that specifically freezes the GUI and this could cause unpredictable issues down the road.

Comment: @Mike-SMT you mentioned that the Tkinter app is frozed and not suitable during sleep calls... Well this is not correct. The app is not frozen and you can click the button, and the call will just start from the beginning. I mean if you click the button during sleep call, you'll simply see the progressbar starting again from the beginning

Comment: There is countless post and documentation about sleep and tkinter. Unless you are using threading and running sleep in a separate thread then sleep does in fact freeze the tkinter instance until sleep has completed.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `sleep()` in tkinter. The entire reason for you problem is `sleep()` will freeze tkinter until it is done with its count so what you are seeing is a frozen program and when the program is finally released its already set to 30 percent on the next mainloop update.

Instead we need to use Tkinter's built in method called `after()` as after is specifically for this purpose.

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

```
mainWindow = tk.Tk()

def update_progress_bar():
    x = barVar.get()
    if x < 100:
        barVar.set(x+10)
        mainWindow.after(500, update_progress_bar)
    else:
        print("Complete")


barVar = tk.DoubleVar()
barVar.set(0)
bar = ttk.Progressbar(mainWindow, length=200, style='black.Horizontal.TProgressbar', variable=barVar, mode='determinate')
bar.grid(row=1, column=0)
button= tk.Button(mainWindow, text='Click', command=update_progress_bar)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

If you want the bar to appear to move smoothly you will need to speed up the function call and reduce the addition to the DoubbleVar.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


mainWindow = tk.Tk()

def update_progress_bar():
    x = barVar.get()
    if x < 100:
        barVar.set(x+0.5)
        mainWindow.after(50, update_progress_bar)
    else:
        print("Complete")


barVar = tk.DoubleVar()
barVar.set(0)
bar = ttk.Progressbar(mainWindow, length=200, style='black.Horizontal.TProgressbar', variable=barVar, mode='determinate')
bar.grid(row=1, column=0)
button= tk.Button(mainWindow, text='Click', command=update_progress_bar)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I only added sleep to simulate processes that takes time... like connecting to a remote server and grabbing some info

Comment: Your answer is not working, the progressbar is hanged till 1.5 sleep seconds pass. I want to see to the progress after each 0.5 sec and as mentioned before using sleep here is a must to simulate long time process

Comment: @AhmedWas then your problem is in some other place in your code or where you are getting your progress from. You cannot use sleep in tkinter for any reason. It just wont work. So please update your code with something that can be tested with the same outcome. On my side my code works perfectly so something else is wrong on your side. Do you have sleep in some other place in your code? Are you importing some method that uses sleep? What exactly are you getting a progress bar of?

Comment: @But why do you think mainWindow.update() is bad solution? I mean it's working fine for me.

Comment: @AhmedWas because the `update()` function is not required as all updates happen in the main loop on every event loop. `sleep()` is 100% wrong to use here. It just doesn't play well with tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling the function when the buttion is initialized, you need to loose the '(barVar') in the command=(barVar)). This way you bind the function to the button and don't call it when initializing it.

```
button= Button(mainWindow, text='Click', command=doNothing)
```

If you need to pass an argument you need to bypass the calling by using lambda:

```
button= Button(mainWindow, text='Click', command= lambda: doNothing(barVar))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated accordingly, but still have the issue of not seeing the progress.

Comment: That may be important to correct however that is not the problem the OP is having.