# Python Tkinter Progressbar After

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Progressbar attached to a variable in Tkinter.
I'm hoping for a solution that when a Progressbar has a full bar, it will add some value to a variable.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()

def start():
    global Probar
    Probar.start(25)

Button = tkinter.Button(text = "Start", command = start).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

Probar = ttk.Progressbar(root)
Probar.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

How could I make this so whenever the progressbar is full, it will change a variable?

Comment: Please provide a copy paste example we can test. This should include the proper imports needed the root tk window and your example here.

Comment: Got it. But I need something that I haven't written. The code is the basic that I can use. I think I would just need a variable attached to the code, but I tried it and it didn't work. @Mike-SMT

Comment: I answered a question about progressbars on this post: [Tkinter: Updating progressbar when a function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51314379/7475225). You can simple edit the part that prints "Complete" to update a variable.

Comment: I checked and they didn't work the way I wanted them to.

Comment: *didn't work the way I wanted them to*... What does that mean? My example over there is exactly what you need. Just changed the print statement to edit a variable and that is the answer to your question.

Comment: Ok. I just wasn't expecting so much more code. Thanks.

Comment: The extra code controls the progress of the bar and then when full do something. that something in my post is a print statement but you can simply change that to edit a variable.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now