# How to link a Progressbar between a python program and a tkinter window?

Tags: python, progress-bar, ttk

I have two .py files in a folder (Main_program.py and HMI.py). The first is a code that contains a large loop (which increments) with a print at the beginning, which displays the evolution of the code execution(10%,20%etc). And the second file is an interface, which contains a button that executes Main_program.py . I would like to create a Progressbar in my interface that would be linked to the evolution of the print in the first code. But how do we do that? thank you very much.

HMI.py :

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from Main_program import run_progessbar
...
root = Tk()
...
jj=0
progessBar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal",length=170,
                             style='black.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
                             mode='determinate', variable=jj)
progessBar.place(x=1060,y=180
...
```

Main_program.py :

```
def run_progessbar():
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib
    ...
    global jj  #without function here jj=0
    while ii > 0 and ii <= np.floor(count / Nbtot):
        if np.remainder(ii,Ni / (10*Nbtot)) == 0:
            jj=jj + 10
            print(str(jj)+'%')
        ...
        ii=ii+1

   #in the shell
    global jj
    SyntaxError: name 'jj' is used prior to global declaration
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter: Updating progressbar when a function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298758/tkinter-updating-progressbar-when-a-function-is-called)

Comment: Did you import in the file Main_programm.py also the file HMI.py? I mean importing it within the your function in order to avoid circular dependency. Or place "jj = 0" as a variable in your function so it does not need to be a global variable.

Comment: if I do that : import HMI in Main_program, a second root window opens immediately without activating the progressbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moab,

Have you tried something like this already?

```
jj = 0
self.progessBar = ttk.Progressbar(self.frame, orient="horizontal", 
                                  length=286, mode="determinate", 
                                  value=jj).pack(pady=10)

def run_progessbar(self):

    global jj
    while ii > 0 and ii <= np.floor(count / Nbtot):
    ...
        jj=jj + 10
        print(str(jj)+'%')
    ...
        ii=ii + 1
```

I found two useful links:

[Tkinter progress bar updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298758/tkinter-updating-progressbar-when-a-function-is-called)

[Progress bar updating](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/388027-update-progressbar-with-tkinter/)

Comment: Hi, yes I tried. In HMI.py I put : `.....                                                      
from Main_program import run_progessbar  root= Tk() ...  jj=0
self.progessBar = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, orient="horizontal",length=286, mode="determinate",value=jj)
self.progessBar.place(x=1180,y=50)` and in Main_program : I put all my code in run_progessbar(self) with global,  but immediately I have: `SyntaxError: name 'jj' is used prior to global declaration`. I have to import run_progressbar into HMI.py, right? sorry for formatt

Comment: Could you please put your code in your question with the proper format? It is quite a pain to read code in a comment.